# Azure Data Factory: Use Lookup result in ForEach loop with Python

Tags: python, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

My pipeline looks like the following:

[image]

> Edit: I think I know why those [ ] in there - from the Python script
> the filenames are returned as a list of filenames. And the Lookup
> activity results then in the following output:

```
 {
                   "count": 1,
                   "value": [
                                     {
                                                        "Prop_0": "['BAT.WISCDD1C.SC.DK002001.D2023191.CSV'",
                                                        "Prop_1": " 'BAT.WISCDD1C.SC.DK002001.TOT.D2023191.CSV'",
                                                        "Prop_2": " 'BAT.WISCDD4C.SC.DK002004.D2023191.CSV'",
                                                        "Prop_3": " 'BAT.WISCDE1C.SC.DK003001.D2023191.CSV'",
                                                        "Prop_4": " 'BAT.WISCDE3C.SC.DK003003.D2023191.CSV'",
                                                        "Prop_5": " 'BAT.WISCDE4C.SC.DK003004.D2023191.CSV'",
                                                        "Prop_6": " 'BAT.WISCDE5C.SC.DK003005.D2023191.CSV'",
                                                        "Prop_7": " 'BAT.WISCDP1C.SC.DK001001.D2023191.CSV'",
                                                        "Prop_8": " 'BAT.WISCDU1C.SC.DK004011.D2023191.CSV'",
                                                        "Prop_9": " 'BAT.WISCDU4C.SC.DK004014.D2023191.CSV'",
                                                        "Prop_10": " 'BAT.WISCDU7C.SC.DK004017.D2023191.CSV']"
                                     }
                   ],
                   "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "integrationRuntime1 (West Europe)",
                   "billingReference": {
                                     "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
                                     "billableDuration": [
                                                        {
                                                                           "meterType": "ManagedVNetIR",
                                                                           "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                                                                           "unit": "Hours"
                                                        }
                                     ]
                   },
                   "durationInQueue": {
                                     "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
                   }
}
```

The ForEach loop should walk through the Prop_ elements and pass them one by one to my Custom Batch Python script.

[image]

In the Batch Custom activity I refer to the items as @{item()} as I guess I should. However, this is how the result looks like when the Python script receives the parameter!

```
    {Prop_0:[
'BAT.WISCDD1C.SC.DK002001.D2023191.CSV',
    Prop_1: 'BAT.WISCDD1C.SC.DK002001.TOT.D2023191.CSV',
    Prop_2: 'BAT.WISCDD4C.SC.DK002004.D2023191.CSV',
    Prop_3: 'BAT.WISCDE1C.SC.DK003001.D2023191.CSV',
    Prop_4: 'BAT.WISCDE3C.SC.DK003003.D2023191.CSV',
    Prop_5: 'BAT.WISCDE4C.SC.DK003004.D2023191.CSV',
    Prop_6: 'BAT.WISCDE5C.SC.DK003005.D2023191.CSV',
    Prop_7: 'BAT.WISCDP1C.SC.DK001001.D2023191.CSV',
    Prop_8: 'BAT.WISCDU1C.SC.DK004011.D2023191.CSV',
    Prop_9: 'BAT.WISCDU4C.SC.DK004014.D2023191.CSV',
    Prop_10: 'BAT.WISCDU7C.SC.DK004017.D2023191.CSV']}
```

I don't understand how to use the Prop_ in the value! I would like to get only one CSV filename per ForEach iteration!

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your support!

Comment: You want to pass the filename from the lookup array to the custom activity parameter inside ForEach right? and your first file name and last file name had `[]`, what you want to do with those? skip it and pass? Can you show the lookup activity output picture for better understanding?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I added the full output to the original post because I can't add a picture in the comment here, and the result was too long. Maybe the returned parameter I provide with the python script is wrong? It is currently " return list(filenames) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your requirement is to get only one CSV filename per ForEach iteration, you can follow the below approach.

After lookup, get the number of `Prop` keys in the object and storing in a string variable by using below expression.

```
@string(sub(length(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),':')), 1))
```

[image]

Now, using this number, create an array of numbers like `[0,1,2,..,10]` and give that to ForEach activity.

```
@range(0,int(variables('num_props')))
```

[image]

Inside ForEach, store the file name from the lookup activity output using the below expression.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0][concat('Prop_',string(item()))]
```

[image]

This will give the file name in the current iteration, but it will have the special characters like this `'BAT.WISCDU7C.SC.DK004017.D2023191.CSV']`.

If you want to remove those, use the below expression which replaces them with empty string.

```
@replace(replace(replace(replace(variables('filename1'), '[', ''),']',''),' ',''),'''','')
```

[image]

Now, give this variable `filename` to your Custom Batch Python script inside ForEach activity. This will pass the filename every iteration to your script.

**My Filename in an iteration:**

[image]

**My Pipeline JSON for your reference:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "sourcecsv_ADLS",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Get the number of Props",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "num_props",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@string(sub(length(split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),':')), 1))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get the number of Props",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@range(0,int(variables('num_props')))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "get current File name using Prop_n",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "filename1",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0][concat('Prop_',string(item()))]",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Replace extra spaces and char",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "get current File name using Prop_n",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "filename",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@replace(replace(replace(replace(variables('filename1'), '[', ''),']',''),' ',''),'''','')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "num_props": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "filename1": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "filename": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```